# Graceful interrupt of EventLoop.sock_accept()

Tags: python, sockets, python-asyncio

Consider the following code, how to stop execution in `listen()`? it seems to hang after `sock.close()` being called. No exceptions are raised

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5

import asyncio, socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(('localhost', 8080))
sock.listen()
sock.setblocking(0)

async def listen():
    print('listen')
    try:
        while True:
            await asyncio.get_event_loop().sock_accept(sock)
            print('accepted')
    except:
        print('exc')

async def stop():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    sock.close()
    print('stopped')


asyncio.ensure_future(listen())
asyncio.ensure_future(stop())
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing the socket or removing the file descriptor using [loop.remove_reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.remove_reader) does not notify [loop.sock_accept](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.sock_accept).

Either cancel it explicitly:

```
# Listening
accept_future = asyncio.ensure_future(loop.sock_accept(sock))
await accept_future
[...]
# Closing
loop.remove_reader(sock.fileno())
sock.close()
accept_future.cancel()
```

or use higher-level coroutines such as [loop.create_server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.create_server) or [asyncio.start_server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.start_server):

```
# Using a protocol factory
server = await loop.create_server(protocol_factory, sock=sock) 
# Using callback and streams
server = await asyncio.start_server(callback, sock=sock)
```